# Why does this JS function returns numbers in ascending order instead of descending order?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am a student learning coding with freeCodeCamp exercises to learn JS. I came across this function in one of the exercises which explains recursion. From what seems logical to me, the function should put numbers from 1 to n in the descending order in the array but when executed, it puts numbers in the ascending order! Why/how does that happen? Does JS execute it in some other way than top-to-bottom or am I missing something here?

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(15));
```

From looking at the code, the code seems to do this: defines constant countArray as countup(n-1) and then adds n as the first element in the array. and then as countup runs with (n-1) adding n-1 as the 2nd element in the array, and the process keeps repeating. but in that case, the numbers in the final array should be [n, n-1, n-2, .... , 3, 2, 1] but the actual result is this array: [1,2,3,..., n-2, n-1, n]. Why/how does it happen this way contrary to what it appears how it should behave?

Comment: Actually, it's in ascending order.

Comment: understand call stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think about what happens during the recursive call.  Maybe this will help:

```
countup(3)
  - calls countup(2)
      - calls countup(1)
          - calls countup(0) - this returns [] right away
          - sets countArray to []
          - pushes 1 onto the array  <--- first number pushed
          - returns [1]
      - sets countArray to [1]
      - pushes 2 onto the array
      - returns [1,2]
  - sets countArray to [1,2]
  - pushes 3 onto the array
  - returns [1,2,3]
```

As you can see, the first time a number is actually pushed onto the array is when it gets down to 1, and then the stack unwinds adding each consecutive number.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array using sort function of javascript.

```js
//function countup(n) {
//  if (n > 1) {
//    return [];
//  } else {
//    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
//    countArray.push(n);
//    return countArray;
//  }
//}
//console.log(countup(15));

//Modified
const countArray = [];
function countup(n) {
    if (n < 1) {
        return [];
    } else {
        countArray.push(n);
        countup(n - 1);
        return countArray;
    }
}
console.log(countup(15));
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question, which asked mostly *why*.  It also has the unfortunate performance characteristic of sorting on every recursive call..